# Generate hash of newly downloaded file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, automation

I'd like my bash script to perform an action every time new file is downloaded to /Downloads (generate hash of downloaded file and send it to API). So far I've been trying to make use of "inotify-tools", but it works only for newly created file and that won't do.

Script should work like this:

1. I download a file via browser (normal way)
2. Script notices new file and is executed automatically

Thanks in advance for help :D

Comment: You should [edit] your question and show your code and describe your example scenario, the actual result you get and the expected result. Then we can better help you to improve your code or maybe suggest alternative solutions.

Comment: Why isn't it working for new files enough? What else do you want to be a trigger?

Comment: @BenjaminW. The browser might use a temporary file for the download and rename the file when the download is finished. Depending on how the browser implements the download, rename or close operations could be relevant events.

Comment: With `inotifywait`, I'd make it print all events (list [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/inotifywait.1.html#EVENTS)) and then see which one is the best one to trigger your activity. Alternatively, you might be able to leverage systemd (see [here](https://www.linux.com/topic/desktop/systemd-services-monitoring-files-and-directories/), for example).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `/etc/crontab` to check `~/Downloads` folder at startup and every n minutes. Script that will run every nth minute can do either

1. Keep the number of files. If number decreases script updates cache. And if number increases then gets the latest created file (or modified) and sends that file's hash to the api via `curl`.
2. Keep the name of files. If a file no longer exists, script then updates the cache of file names. If a new file appears again hashes and sends hash to the api via `curl`.

You can keep cache of files under `/tmp`.

If you can provide an example scenario I can write a simple script